# ZMQ pub apparently not working with XAMPP on windows and php

Tags: php, xampp, zeromq, publish-subscribe

This question is so specific I'm afraid nobody will be able to help me... I've switched from developing on a mac to a pc, and have all of my project working on the local machine (using XAMPP) apart from my ZMQ socket.

ZMQ is clearly working because when I push messages to the pull socket, it receives the message (so pull and push seem to be working fine). But when the message is then published, nothing seems to pick it up. At first I thought it was the client (flash based), but strangely enough when I connect to the online server (which has the same code for the socket) it receives the published messages without a problem. I tried writing a little zmq subscribe socket and then test it with a publish socket, but that doesn't seem to respond either. I'm more than a little stumped.

This is the code for the socket (with made-up port numbers):

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$pub = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB);
$pub->bind("tcp://*:4321");
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind("tcp://*:4322");

while (true) {
    $request = $pull->recv();
    $pub->send($request);
    echo PHP_EOL."PUBLISHING: $request".PHP_EOL;
}
```

I've tried opening the ports on windows firewall, then turning off firewall all together but that's not the problem. Could it be the ZMQ installation? or the php binding? It seems to have loaded correctly when I check phpinfo() and it's the same version as on the server (which works). Is there something basic that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else has these kinds of problems, just to let you know that it was to do with non-matching zmq versions with the php binding. Though a lot of zmq stuff was working, the actionscript zmq script wasn't responding correctly. Strangely enough phpinfo() was showing that I was indeed using zmq 3.2.2 but "php -i" revealed that it was 3.2.0. I don't know if it's necessary to put libzmq.dll and php_zmq.dll in System32, but I had, and I think that during my fiddling to get everything installed I'd got my dlls mixed up. After deleting everything and using only dlls from here:

https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/issues/79

I was able to resolve the issue. I hope this helps others!